# Github action deploy docker to AWS ECS ECR

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, github-actions, aws-ecr

Hi I want to use Github action to build and push my github repo's frontend and backend images to AWS ECR.

How change this part of the Github action's config??

```
- name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
  id: build-image
  env:
    ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
    ECR_REPOSITORY: githubactions
    IMAGE_TAG: latest
  run: |
    # Build a docker container and
    # push it to ECR so that it can
    # be deployed to ECS.
    docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
    docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
    echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

Lets say in my Github repository, I have two images with web/Dockerfile and backend/Dockerfile

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use `docker build -f PATH` and run the build+push commands twice, either as additional commands in the same step:

```
- name: Build, tag, and push images to Amazon ECR
  id: build-image
  env:
    ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
  run: |
    docker build -f backend/Dockerfile -t $ECR_REGISTRY/backend:latest .
    docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/backend:latest
    docker build -f web/Dockerfile -t $ECR_REGISTRY/web:latest .
    docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/web:latest
```

Or two separate steps:

```
- name: Build, tag, and push backend image to Amazon ECR
  id: build-backend
  env:
    ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
    ECR_REPOSITORY: backend
    IMAGE_TAG: latest
  run: |
    docker build -f backend/Dockerfile -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
    docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
    echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"

- name: Build, tag, and push web image to Amazon ECR
  id: build-web
  env:
    ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
    ECR_REPOSITORY: web
    IMAGE_TAG: latest
  run: |
    docker build -f web/Dockerfile -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
    docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
    echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"
```